# Facing Problem with dbt-duckdb adapter due incompatible issue with dbt-core

Tags: dbt, duckdb

I trying to configure the dbt with duckdb

I installed `pip install dbt-duckdb`

when i run the `dbt --version` i can’t able to see the dbt-duckdb plugin

`dbt --version
Core:

- installed: 1.3.1
- latest: 1.4.5 - Update available!

Your version of dbt-core is out of date!
You can find instructions for upgrading here:

Plugins:

- postgres: 1.3.1 - Update available!

At least one plugin is out of date or incompatible with dbt-core.
You can find instructions for upgrading here:

And this is my profile.yml configuration
duckdb:
outputs:
dev:
type: duckdb
path: ‘/tmp/my_duckdb.db’
target: dev

and when i run `dbt debug`

i am facing this error

1 check failed:
Profile loading failed for the following reason:
Runtime Error
Credentials in profile “duckdb”, target “dev” invalid: Runtime Error
Could not find adapter type duckdb!

And my duckdb version is `0.6.1`

Any idea what is causing this problem. Let me know if there are any other details that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is a Python environment issue: the latest version of `dbt-duckdb` (which is what you should get when you run `pip install dbt-duckdb`) has a dependency on dbt-core 1.4.0, but the environment that you're trying to run dbt in is using dbt-core version 1.3.1.

There are a couple of options I suggest:

1. The best practice would be to use a virtual environment for your dbt-duckdb installation; see https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/core/install-pip-best-practices.md
2. The second-best practice would be to try to figure out which environment your dbt-core 1.3.1 version is living in and install a compatible version of dbt-duckdb inside of it using `pip install dbt-duckdb~=1.3.0`.

Hope that helps! If you have more details you would like me to look at (I'm the developer of dbt-duckdb) I'd love it if you posted them on the [issues page for the project](https://github.com/jwills/dbt-duckdb/issues) or in the #db-duckdb channel in the dbt Slack.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And it is because of the python environment 